# Set and read cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I use the following jquery code to set my profile image. But I would like to store it in a cookie. But whatever I try it won't work. could someone help?

setting var bgCover = $.cookie("bgCover"); didn't work

```
function setCover() {

            var profileContainer = $('#coverHeader'),
                coverContainer = $('#coverGallery'),
                coverThumbBox = $('.gr-item');


            $('.use-cover').click(function () {
                var bgCover = $(this).closest(coverThumbBox).data("src"),
                    elem = $(this).closest(coverThumbBox);

                // Add text style to header. Find cat_dark or cat_light in to item

                if ((elem).hasClass('cat_dark')) {
                    profileContainer.removeClass('theme-inverse').addClass('theme-default');
                }
                else {
                    profileContainer.removeClass('theme-default').addClass('theme-inverse');
                }

                elem.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');


                // Set backround to profile header

              profileContainer.css("background-image", "url(/themes/site_themes/dashboard/img/cover/full/" + bgCover + ".jpg)");

                return false;
            });

            // remove backround to profile header
            $('.reset-cover').click(function () {
                profileContainer.removeClass('theme-default theme-inverse').css("background-image", "");
                coverContainer.find(coverThumbBox, '.active').removeClass('active')
            });

        }
      setCover();
```

added to var:

```
            bgCover = $.cookie("bgCover");
```

changed at profileContainer.css:

```
            $.cookie("bgCover", bgCover, { expires: 7 });
            profileContainer.css("background-image", "url(/themes/site_themes/dashboard/img/cover/full/" + $.cookie("bgCover") + ".jpg)");
```

Didn't work.

Comment: `But I am not able to` - why not?

Comment: Because what ever I try it won't work (yes I include the cookie plug-in)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables why -1????

Comment: you know, other people have looked at this page besides me.  Also, *edit your question* to show what you have tried.  Simply saying "wahtever I try won't work" doesn't tell us anything, because *we don't know what all that includes*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it....

```
       function setCover() {

            var profileContainer = $('#coverHeader'),
                coverContainer = $('#coverGallery'),
                coverThumbBox = $('.gr-item'),
                bgCover = $.cookie("bgCover");

            $('.use-cover').click(function () {
                var bgCover = $(this).closest(coverThumbBox).data("src"),
                    elem = $(this).closest(coverThumbBox);

                // Add text style to header. Find cat_dark or cat_light in to item

                if ((elem).hasClass('cat_dark')) {
                    profileContainer.removeClass('theme-inverse').addClass('theme-default');
                }
                else {
                    profileContainer.removeClass('theme-default').addClass('theme-inverse');
                }

                elem.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');


                // Set backround to profile header
               $.cookie("bgCover", bgCover);
               profileContainer.css("background-image", "url(/themes/site_themes/dashboard/img/cover/full/" + bgCover + ".jpg)");

                return false;
            });

            // remove backround to profile header
            $('.reset-cover').click(function () {
            $.cookie('bgCover', null);
                profileContainer.removeClass('theme-default theme-inverse').css("background-image", "url(/themes/site_themes/dashboard/img/cover/full/cover50.jpg)");
                coverContainer.find(coverThumbBox, '.active').removeClass('active')
            });

        }
      setCover();


       $(function() {
       if($.cookie('bgCover') == null) {
       $("#coverHeader").css("background-image", "url(/themes/site_themes/dashboard/img/cover/full/cover50.jpg)");
      } else {
       $("#coverHeader").css("background-image", "url(/themes/site_themes/dashboard/img/cover/full/" + $.cookie('bgCover') + ".jpg)");
      }
      });
```